# Turn directory to file in dired

Tags: dired, files, directories

I often make the mistake of creating a directory instead of a file in Dired (by hitting `+`). I then have to delete it and recreate the file, with the same name.

Sometimes, I tried to edit the `d` file type attribute (with `Ctrl x - Ctrl q`)

```
total used in directory 8.0K available 20.3 GiB
drwxrwsr-x 2 smonff users   6 Aug 17 18:41 demand.t
-rw-rw-r-- 1 smonff users 170 Aug 17 11:33 user.t
-rw-rw-r-- 1 smonff users 838 Aug 17 18:04 location.t
```

...but I am not aware of a way to edit the files attributes, Emacs says that they are read-only, even after turning to *Editable Dired* mode

Comment: You want `dired-mode` to help you convert a directory into a file?  I could be wrong, but the usual method is to delete the unwanted directory and then create a new file in separate actions.

Comment: So write a command that deletes the directory (*if* it is empty) and creates a zero-length file of the same name, and bind it to a key (or do it with a keyboard macro if you don't want to write Lisp).

Comment: What both @lawlist and NickD said.